# How can I add an icon to the right of the text in a popup menu item?

Tags: android

Play Music uses an icon in the menu to show whether an item is saved on the device.

[image]

What's the best way to do this in my app? If the answer is to create a ListView inside a PopupWindow, then how do I style a list so that it looks just like a PopupMenu?

Comment: You might consider posting a screenshot somewhere and linking to it, so we know what you are referring to, as not everybody uses Play Music or will necessarily recognize what you are seeking.

Comment: Screenshot added. Thanks.

Comment: You can use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to try to inspect the Play Music UI and see what that is. I have never tried **`uiautomatorviewer`** with a popup like that, but I presume it handles that somehow.

Comment: I didn't know about that trick. It is indeed a list view.